# Quick comparison of two columns in other TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

How to quickly find values ​​in a column that does not contain another column in another table

The problem is the speed of the query that is dynamically built in "execute immediate "stmt and average size of test tables  test_table = 40mln and test_table2 = 1mln

Unfortunately I've been able to find similar topics and i will be grateful for any help

My queries:

```
select pole2 from test_table tt
 where exists( select 1 from test_table2 tt2
                   where tt2.pole1 = 'ABC'
                   and   tt.pole2 != tt.pole2)

select pole2 from test_table tt
 where pole2 not in ( select pole2 from test_table2 tt2
                   where tt2.pole1 = 'ABC')
```

Comment: You realize that this queries are not the same?